# Kafka Consumer in C++

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, consumer

I have been searching for C++ kafka consumer. I came across following which are for C++ kafka but there is no consumer.

https://github.com/adobe-research/libkafka (Only sample producer)

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/tree/master/src-cpp

Does anyone have C++ kafka consumer based on the above work or any new way for C++ kafka consumer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

librdkafka's examples/ directory contains a C++ consumer (and producer):

High-level balanced KafkaConsumer:
https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_complex_consumer_example.cpp

Low-level legacy Consumer:
https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.cpp#L395

Comment: I found kafka nuget package by you but it is pre-release. Can you please confirm me when its release is scheduled?

Comment: Working on it as we speak, there will be experimental (but hopefully working) packages within a couple of weeks.

Comment: That would be highly appreciated sir. :)

Answer (score 9):

As a follow up on Edenhill's answer, you can try [cppkafka](https://github.com/mfontanini/cppkafka), a high level C++11 wrapper for *librdkafka*. There's some examples in there for you to look at.

Comment: librdkafka for c++ programmers is hard to learn, e.g. do not know how to config topic name in example cpp file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use modern cpp, you can use this wrapper around librdkafka [modern-cpp-kafka](https://github.com/morganstanley/modern-cpp-kafka)